# What am I doing wrong with this dummy battery for my camera?

Tags: batteries, pcb, current, charging

Im trying to make a camera battery grip for a Canon M50 that uses LPE12 batteries. They output 7.2V.

I'm using this PCB to try and convert 3.7V coming from a 18650 battery to the appropriate level:

[image: this PCB]

I was able to get the correct voltage but it is still not working:

[image: voltage]

[image: my setup]

[image: battery contact]

[image: cut original cable]

EDIT: I did some more tests and it turns out that the original coupler supplies the dummy battery 8V 1Amp if plugged in to a USB power bank and the same on a wallwart charger. When I remove the 18650 battery from the circuit and power the pcb through its microb usb charging port I do manage to get 8V 0.9Amp which is close enough i would suppose. When I plug it into the camera, the voltage did drop to 5V indicating that it's not able to sustain power. Which I was slightly expecting because of Dave's observation that my pcb didnt have the proper electrolytic capacitors to sustain the power. But it all seems to go batshit once I put the battery back on the circuit. I couldn't seem to measure the output Amp of the board because it seems to go over the scale. I even tried to limit the current by adding a 8ohm resistor to try and limit the circuit to 1Amp but all it does is make the resistor go hot.

Comment: what about the correct current? ... is the voltage staying near 7.2 V when you turn on the camera?

Comment: So you get out a correct voltage, but it isn't working? What it should output?

Comment: @Marko it should output 7.2V i dont really know what the draw current of the camera is though.

Comment: @jsotola the voltage does stay near at 7.2V. I am suspecting an issue with current but my multimeter only goes upto 0.25A in measuring, so I cant really test for that.

Comment: the voltage would drop under load if the power supply was unable to supply the required current .... did you miss an electrical connection in the battery compartment?

Comment: @jsotola i measured the voltage going to the contact pads on the battery coupler. It's getting the correct 7.2v. The voltage stays the same whether I put the camera on the on or off position.

Comment: What are the booster specs? Link to product?

Comment: @Bruce Abbot. Here's the link to the shop's page https://shopee.ph/product/226548939/5217741101?smtt=0.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

So it did turn out to be a power supply issue. I used 2 18650 batteries instead of 1 in a parallel holder. Dont worry, I made sure to balance them before putting them on. I connected the charging board to the circuitry of the original coupler. I set the incoming voltage to 3.7 for the coupler. And it outputs 8v to the dummy. It turns on for the most part and Im able to take photos and videos. But I cant do burst shooting though. It will cause the camera to crash. And the only way to turn it back on by inserting the default battery pack.

Edit: I found a better solution. So i just hooked up the coupler board to the batteries directly. And i hooked up the charging board tangent to the line feeding into the coupler from the battery to be able to charge it as well. This now solves the amperage issue. [image]

Answer (score 1):

[The Canon LPE12 battery has four terminals.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VF5W5F1)

[image]

Two are power.  One of the others is probably a temperature sensor for the charger.

The fourth terminal is usually some kind of identification pin.  It may be as simple as a resistor indicating the capacity of the battery, or it may be as complicated as some kind of encrypted digital query from the camera to the battery.

You have to figure out what the other two pins do, and emulate those functions in your battery grip.

The camera probably checks both of the extra pins and won't work if either gives an incorrect result.

Comment: I do have another identical coupler that I plug in via USB to either a computer or power bank and it works. I actually just clipped off the part that goes into the coupler and soldered it to the pcb, it only seemed to be the power leads. So if there is some sort of data check it would be on the dummy battery. It works via USB but not on my little contraption.

Comment: You might mention that in the question.  You could also include pictures of it.  You may have split part of the circuitry when you clipped off the coupler.

Comment: Updated the post with the picture of the original usb cable component beside my new setup.

Answer (score 1):

I have powered Canon cameras externally using a custom power supply in an aerial photography application. I found that they can draw very narrow peaks of current approaching 2A at times, and your power supply needs to be able to handle that without any significant voltage droop.

See those large electrolytic capacitors in the Canon battery replacement circuit? That's what they're for. Just looking at the picture of your generic board, I would guess that it can't handle such large peaks.

Comment: I am suspecting that it might be an amperage issue. Do you think it would it help if i supplied the pcb a battery of 2 18650cells in parallel?

Comment: I doubt it. The board itself doesn't appear to be able to handle that kind of current.

Comment: Just a thought. So what if I use the circuit of the original coupler as the output and put in my board as the input power? I just basically needed it to charge the battery without taking it out. Otherwise I would put it on the input of the coupler directly.

Comment: Maybe. It's impossible to say for sure, since there are so few technical details available for that board. All you can do is try it and see.

Comment: So I did try it. And unfortunately no its still not working. And I don't think it producing noise is a good thing. Curiously though I did try to measure the Amps flowing through the output before I did that when it was just powered through a microb usb and it was outputting 0.8Amp and when I connected it to the battery board it was spiking above what my reader could handle.